# Creating mouse cursor/pointers in OS X Leopard

Tags: css, macos, mouse-cursor

I have a small gif that I can use as a mouse pointer with a browser by doing something like:

```
.myclass
 {
   cursor:  url("mycursor.gif");
 }
```

This works OK except that the hotspot is in the wrong place. Anyone know of any OSX Leopard software I can use to set the hotspot? I might be able to do it with Rezilla but I don't know what Safari etc are expecting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS 3 cursor specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor):

```
.myclass { cursor: url("mycursor.gif") 10 20 }
```